# Redis: How to give an unique id to hashes

Tags: redis

I want to save my users information in hashes. I want to create a hash for each user in the application.
The hashes name is like this: "user:1001"
Now, i want to users id start from 1000 and increase by one.
how can i do this? 
thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have a key called `user:id`, which will be a number that you will increment to obtain new ids. In your case, you can set the initial value to 1000:

```
SET user:id 1000
```

Then by using `INCR` you will be able to get a new id for your next user:

```
INCR user:id
```

Depending on the language you use, there may be already some tools to solve this problem. I would recommend you check [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/), or [one of the ports](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/#related-projects).

Comment: thanks. i have node.js server. how can i save this for next time that i run the server? (i know it's away from the question ;) )

Comment: If you want that number to be persistent after a redis-server restart, you have some options like replication, snapshots and an append-only log. The best solution will depend on your use case, you can read about them in this article: http://redis.io/topics/persistence